# как поменять данные в связанной таблице?Laravel

Tags: laravel

Нужно изменить поля в связанной модели(таблице)
в данном случае sale_price, regular_price

есть модель:

```
class Product{
   public function sku()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SKU::class);
    }
}

таблица от модели sku
sku
имеет:
id  int(10) unsigned 
regular_price   decimal(8,2)    
sale_price
product_id 

//Вот я получаю все товары
$products = Product::all();
  foreach ($products as $product){
     $product->sku->regular_price = 1;
     $product->sku()->save(); //так что-то не работает ошибка
     $product->update(); //так тоже не меняет regular_price но все работает т.е обновляет просто наверно модель $product
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове

```
    $product->sku();
```

вы получаете не коллекцию, а объект `QueryBuilder`

А при вызове

```
    $product->sku;
```

Назад вернется уже отработанный запрос, запись выше эквивалентна

```
    $product->sku()->all();
```

Ошибка уже должна быть на этапе

```
    $product->sku->regular_price = 1;
```

Где вы пытаетесь для коллекции определить свойство `regular_price`

Так как `Product` может иметь множество `SKU` о чем говорит `HasMany`, нужно явно указывать какую запись `SKU` нужно изменять. Все или какую-то конкретную.

Если нужно изменить все записи, правильно будет написать например

```
    $products = Product::all();
    
    $newPrice = 10;

    foreach ($products as $product) 
    {
            $product->sku->each(function($sku) use ($newPrice) {
                    $sku->regular_price = $newPrice;
                    $sku->update();
            });
    }
```

вы видите пример перечисления через `foreach`, так и с использованием анонимной функции

Answer (score 0):

нужно так:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
                $sale_price = 40;
                $product->sku()->update(['sale_price' => $sale_price]);
            }
```